# Doubt about the relationships in the Semantic Triangle

Tags: semantics, linguistics

I was reading the wiki on [The Semantic Triangle<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_reference), but it is not as good, so I have few doubts:
[image]

- As I read on many places an example for the vertices could be (I may have written incorrectly):

  - Thought: insect, 2 wings, 6 legs
  - Symbol: Fly /flʌɪ/
  - Referent: Real world object, fly
- Now the relation between symbol and thought should be correct, we can't use the wrong word.
- the bottom line is dotted since there is no fixed relation, e.g.
  Dog can be related to bow-wow or vow-vow in English or German. Thus we need to go through the Thought as an intermediate.

I'm not entirely clear with the rest of it so, Now I have few questions:

- What does Adequate and True refer to?
- What is the difference between casual and imputed relation?
- The terms: CORRECT, TRUE, ADEQAUTE. Which property of the relationship are these?
  P.S. someone add a semantic-triangle or semiotic-triangle tag.

Comment: The diagram was published in Ogden and Richards, and those are their labels and annotations. As to what they mean, your guess is as good as mine; O&R were not very semantically sophisticated. As the article points out, this is the place where [Nominalists and Realists](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/nominalists.html) part intellectual company.

Answer (score 1):

The schema is from:

- [Charles Key Ogden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Kay_Ogden) & [Ivor Armstrong Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._A._Richards), [The Meaning of Meaning : A Study of the Influence of Language upon Thought and of the Science of Symbolism](https://books.google.it/books?id=EPeVQgAACAAJ) (1923), page 11 (modified from [C.S.Peirce](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-semiotics/)).

See page 9:

> Symbols direct and organize, record and communicate. In stating what they direct and organize, record and communicate we have to distinguish as always between Thoughts and Things.It is Thought (or *reference*) which is directed and organized, and it is also Thought which is recorded and communicated.

See page 11:

> Between a thought and a symbol causal relations holds. When we speak, the symbols we employ is caused partly by the reference we are making [...].
>
> Between the Thought and the Referent there is also a relation; nore or less direct [...].
>
> Between the symbol and the referent there is no relevant relation other than the indirect one, which consists in its being used by someone to stand for a referent.

And see page 102:

> It will be convenient here to define a true Symbol as distinghuised from a true Reference: A true symbol [set of words: proposition or sentence] = one which correctly records an adequate reference. [...] It correctly records an adequate reference when it will cause a similar reference to occur in a suitable interpreter [the subject partecipating to the process of *communication*]. It is false when it records an inadequate reference.
>
> It is often of great importance to distinguish between false anc incorrect propositions. An incorrect symbol is one which in a given universe of discourse causes in a suitable interpreter a refernce different from that symbolized in the speaker.